# How is "getDataDir()" different from getFilesDir?

Tags: android

The "getDataDir()" that returns a File object has been added from API 24. If it is used, It requires the minimum API level to be 24.

The documentation explains its use as :

> Returns the absolute path to the directory on the filesystem where all private files belonging to this app are stored. ***Apps should not use this path directly***; they should instead use *getFilesDir()*, getCacheDir(), getDir(String, int), or other storage APIs on this class.
>
> The returned path may change over time if the calling app is moved to an adopted storage device, so only relative paths should be persisted.
>
> No additional permissions are required for the calling app to read or write files under the returned path.

How is : getDataDir() (added in API 24) different from getFilesDir() or Environment.getDataDirectory() ?

In what possible scenarios can the function be used?. I am aware of the path functions existing <=23

Answer (score 4):

The directory returned by `getFilesDir()` will be inside `getDataDir()`. Neither has anything to do with `Environment.getDataDirectory()`, which returns the root of all internal storage.

> In what possible scenarios can the function be used?

One scenario would be implementing some sort of in-app full backup of all files on internal storage for that app.

Comment: What's the best way to get data dir for API levels < 24?

Comment: @frogatto: I have never looked for that, sorry.

Comment: @frogatto:
ApplicationInfo appInfo = context.getApplicationInfo()
appInfo.dataDir will give the internal app root folder path.

Comment: @frogatto ContextCompat.getDataDir(context) works pre and post 24